# ajax return single variable and an array variable

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I have a comment form that requests a newtimestamp and newcomment variables.  The newtimestamp variable is a single variable and the newcomment variable is an array returned from a foreach loop.

ajaxrequest.php:

```
foreach ($array2 as $print2) {
$var1 = $print2['var'];

$newtimestamp = $now;
$newcomment = "<div class=post>$var1</div>";


echo json_encode(array('newtimestamp' => $newtimestamp, 'newcomment' => $newcomment));
}
```

I then use ajax to prepend the new comment's and set the newtimestamp on a hidden input field.

ajax:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#commentform').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
    url:'ajaxrequest.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(data, response){

$("#posts").fadeOut(300);                          
$("#posts").prepend(data.newcomment);
$("#time").val(data.newtimestamp);
$("#posts").fadeIn(500);
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#posts').offset().top - 100 }, 'fast');     
        console.log(data);  

    },
    error:function(data){

                console.log(data);      
    }
    });

e.preventDefault();
return false;

});
});
```

The above method gives me a success message in console, the prepend works but only shows 1 result everytime when it should show all results from the last timestamp.  The prepend and setting the value of the hidden input field do not work if the user posts a second, third etc comment.

console:

```
Object {newtimestamp: "2014-11-19 07:59:48", newcomment: "<div>a new comment</div> 1"}
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

I need to return the newtimestamp variable as a single variable (not an array) and set this on a hidden input field value, and I need to return the newcomment variable as an array that can be prepended to a div.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you include `dataType : 'json'` in ajax call

Comment: Can you post the PHP response ??

Comment: I have updated the question : the prepend works but only shows 1 result everytime when it should show all results from the last timestamp.

Comment: `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);` have you use this??

Answer (score 0):

Change your php file. I am not sure this is you are expecting.

ajaxrequest.php:

```
foreach ($array2 as $print2) {
$var1 = $print2['var'];

$newtimestamp[] = $now;
$newcomment[] = "<div class=post>$var1</div>";


}

echo json_encode(array('newtimestamp' => $newtimestamp, 'newcomment' => $newcomment));
```

Comment: This will return a json string like `{"newtimestamp" : ["data","data","data"],"newcomment" : ["data","data","data"]}` which is not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your php code like this

```
$data = array();
foreach ($array2 as $print2) {
    $var1 = $print2['var'];

    $newtimestamp = $now;
    $newcomment = "<div class=post>$var1</div>";
    $data['data'][] = array('newtimestamp' => $newtimestamp, 'newcomment' => $newcomment);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

now the JSON response will look something like

```
{"data" : [{"newtimestamp" : 72345654,"newcomment" : "comment data"},{"newtimestamp" : 72345654,"newcomment" : "comment data"}]}
```

loop through array of objects using jQuery `each`. The final code will look something like this.

```
$.each($response.data,function(index,value){
    $("#posts").prepend(value.newcomment);
    $("#time").val(value.newtimestamp);
})
```

NOTE: either send `application/json` header (so that the response will be parsed and converted to an js object by default) or parse it after receiving. This action should happen before the `each` loop

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are echo multiple JSON string. You need to echo a single JSON string with all data.

Try something like the code below, this worked for me. You only need to fit this into your jQuery and PHP code.

```
<?php
    $jsonArray = array();
    $array2 = array(array('var'=>1),array('var'=>2));
    foreach ($array2 as $print2) 
    {
        $var1 = $print2['var'];

        $newtimestamp = time();
        $newcomment = "<div class=post>$var1</div>";


        $jsonArray[] = array('newtimestamp' => $newtimestamp, 'newcomment' => $newcomment);
    }
    print_r($jsonArray);
    $data = json_encode($jsonArray);

?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var data = jQuery.parseJSON('<?=$data?>');

    $.each(data, function(item, value){
        console.log(value['newtimestamp']);
    });
</script>
```